# Incorrect routes for Devise + LinkedIn (OmniAuth)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, devise, linkedin-api, omniauth

I am trying to implement sign up through LinkedIn to the current Devise gem. These are the current routes:

```
devise_for :users, :path_names => { :sign_in => 'login', :sign_out => 'logout', :password => 'secret',
                                    :confirmation => 'verification', :unlock => 'unlock', :registration => 'register',
                                    :sign_up => 'signup' }, :controllers => {:omniauth_callbacks => "omniauth_callbacks"}
```

And the view: `= link_to "Sign in with Linkedin",user_omniauth_authorize_path(:linkedin)`
Returns to this error:

```
No route matches {:controller=>"omniauth_callbacks", :action=>"passthru", :provider=>:linkedin, :format=>nil} missing required keys: [:provider]
```

I've tried to add **provider** key too, like: `= link_to "Sign in with Linkedin",user_omniauth_authorize_path(:provider => 'linkedin')`

But then I got:

```
No route matches {:controller=>"omniauth_callbacks", :action=>"passthru", :provider=>"linkedin"} missing required keys: [:provider]
```

What am I missing at this point?

Thank you very much

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add the line in `devise.rb`

```
config.omniauth :linkedin, 'APP_ID', 'APP_SECRET'
```

Devise will automatically add a signin link using linkedin.

In `omniauth_callbacks_controller.rb` add a method as:-

```
def linkedin
  #code for authorization using linkedin callback credentials
end
```